# Add two longs brings a lower result

Tags: java, android, math, long-integer

I want to add 35 days to my starting day. I get a result lower than the starting day.

Here is the code :

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, dpickerListener, g_year, g_month, g_day);
DatePicker dp = dpd.getDatePicker();
System.out.println("g_DateCycle.getTime()" + g_DateCycle.getTime());
dp.setMinDate(g_DateCycle.getTime());
long FinCycle=g_DateCycle.getTime();
System.out.println("FinCycle : " + FinCycle);
FinCycle= FinCycle +(g_GridDayNumber*(24*60*60*1000));
System.out.println("FinCycle : " + FinCycle);
dp.setMaxDate(FinCycle);
return dpd;
```

I got an error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromDate: Sun Jan 31 00:00:00 CET 2016 does not precede toDate: Sat Jan 16 06:57:12 CET 2016
```

and the following output:

```
02-03 16:52:16.724 20157-20157/com.inverseo.marc.t372lematin I/System.out: g_DateCycle.getTime()1454194800000
02-03 16:52:16.724 20157-20157/com.inverseo.marc.t372lematin I/System.out: FinCycle : 1454194800000
02-03 16:52:16.724 20157-20157/com.inverseo.marc.t372lematin I/System.out: FinCycle : 1452923832704
```

I can't figure out why when adding `g_GridDayNumber*(24*60*60*1000)` with `g_GridDayNumber=35`, I can get a lower long !

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`35*(24*60*60*1000) = 3,024,000,000` which is greater than max value allowed by integers in Java and becomes `-1,270,967,296` in two's complement.

Specify one of those as a long and it should work. Notice the L to specify long after the number 24 below:

```
35*(24L*60*60*1000)
```

Comment: That' what I've tried, doing : long FinCycle=...
Sorry : I didn't saw the L.